# Images are not resizing after dynamically adding Imageviews in relative layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, imageview, android-imageview

I am trying to create photo collage app. Here I am dynamically adding imageviews in relative layout by passing array of positions for creating grid. Grids are successfully created. But when I add images, the images aren't scaled properly or not fitting to entire imageview's area. Also when I add touch listener on images, images are moviing outside the area of imageview.Please help me in this.Thanks in advance Here is my code

```
public void drawGrids() {
    Resources res = getResources();
    int Rid = c.id;

    TypedArray ta = res.obtainTypedArray(Rid);
    int n = ta.length();
    String[][] array = new String[n][];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int id = ta.getResourceId(i, 0);
        if (id > 0) {
            array[i] = res.getStringArray(id);
            Log.e(" array", "" + i + " " + Arrays.toString(array[i]));
            String[] values = Arrays.toString(array[i]).replaceAll("[\\[\\]\\s]", "").split(","); // extracting each element from array

            final int position = i;

            limit = position+1;
            float x = Float.parseFloat(values[0]);
            float y = Float.parseFloat(values[1]);
            float w = Float.parseFloat(values[2]);
            float h = Float.parseFloat(values[3]);
            Log.e(" x:", "" + x);
            Log.e(" y:", "" + y);
            Log.e(" w:", "" + w);
            Log.e(" h:", "" + h);

            img1 = new ImageView(getActivity());

            img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_background);         

            params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int) ((Screen_width * w) - padding), (int) ((Screen_height * h) - padding));

            // x= x* Screen_width
            // y= y* Screen_height
            params.leftMargin = (int) ((Screen_width * x) + padding);
            params.topMargin = (int) ((Screen_height * y) + padding);
            params.rightMargin = padding;
            params.bottomMargin = padding;
            Log.e(" px(x):", "" + (int) (Screen_width * x));
            Log.e(" px(y):", "" + (int) (Screen_height * y));
            Log.e(" px(w):", "" + (int) (Screen_width * w));
            Log.e("px(h)", "" + (int) (Screen_height * h));

            if(!mSelectedImages.isEmpty()) {
                onPickedSuccessfully(mSelectedImages);
            }
            else {
                img1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Log.e("clicked", "" + position);
                        onClickPickImageMultipleWithLimit(img1);
                    }
                });
            }

        IMGS.add(img1);  // arraylist of imageview
            root1.addView(img1, params);
            createPreview();
        } else {
            // something wrong with the XML
        }
    }

    ta.recycle(); 


}

 public void onPickedSuccessfully(ArrayList<ImageEntry> images) { //     selected images path are to be fetched here
      mSelectedImages = images;


        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (j = 0; j <IMGS.size(); j++) {

                    final ImageView child=IMGS.get(j);

                    child.onTouchListener(new MultiTouchListener);// multitouch listener for zooming and scrolling picked image 
                    Log.e("w n h", "" + child.getWidth() + " " + child.getHeight());

                    int areaheight = child.getWidth();
                    int areawidth = child.getHeight();

                    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    oldBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String.valueOf(mSelectedImages.get(j)), bmOptions);//decodeFile(String.valueOf(mSelectedImages.get(j)));

                    int height = oldBitmap.getHeight(), width = oldBitmap.getWidth();
                    Log.e(" b width and height ", "" + oldBitmap.getWidth() + " " + oldBitmap.getHeight());
                    Log.e(" area width and height ", "" + areawidth + " " + areaheight);

                    Bitmap scaledBitmap;
                    if (areaheight > areawidth) {
                        // portrait
                        float ratio = (float) height / areaheight;
                        height = areaheight;
                        width = (int) (width / ratio);
                        scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(oldBitmap, width, height, true);
                        Log.e("porait scaled w ht ", "" + scaledBitmap.getWidth() + " " + scaledBitmap.getHeight());

                    } else if (areawidth > areaheight) {
                        //landscape
                        float ratio = (float) width / areawidth;
                        width = areawidth;
                        height = (int) (height / ratio);
                        scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(oldBitmap, width, height, true);
                        Log.e("landscape scaled w ht ", "" + scaledBitmap.getWidth() + " " + scaledBitmap.getHeight());
                    } else {
                        // square
                        height = areaheight;
                        width = areawidth;
                        scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(oldBitmap, width, height, true);
                        Log.e("square scaled w ht ", "" + scaledBitmap.getWidth() + " " + scaledBitmap.getHeight());

                    }
                    child.setImageBitmap(scaledBitmap);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Sorry for question, but why you don't want to user RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager to work with grid of images, it will save your memory?

Comment: Because I have grids of images. when i select any image i want to draw grids according to that so for that i have saved postions in an array. And I am not sure how to do it with Recycler view where I can just give spansize

Answer (score 1):

In your case you need to add line:

```
img1.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP); // or CENTER_INSIDE, or FIT_CENTER, or for example FIT_XY
```

after:

```
img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_background);
```

Thus, you will provide scaling for all images that will be set into your ImageView. You can read more about scaleType [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) and [here](http://etcodehome.blogspot.ru/2011/05/android-imageview-scaletype-samples.html)

Comment: thanks, If i set centerCrop it will cut off other parts of image. I want to display some portion of image and then scroll on image to show other portion

Comment: If you will go to the second link, you will find for example MATRIX scale type it will scale your image to whole screen, but will show in the imageView only part, so you will able to, for example, drag it (imageview) and see other parts of image.

Comment: Also, as I know, you can specify matrix through `void setImageMatrix (Matrix matrix)`

Comment: after setting matrix image gets cropped

Comment: I wrote that you can customize matrix through `setImageMatrix`, did you play with that function?

Comment: your comment was helpful

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use ImageView and setOnTouchListener, you may try this custom view.

```
public class ScaleImageView extends ImageView {

private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
private float mScaleFactor = 1.0f;
private float x = 0;
private float y = 0;
private float tx = 0;
private float ty = 0;
private float dx = 0;
private float dy = 0;
private int scrollLimitX = 0;
private int scrollLimitY = 0;
private boolean justScaled = false;

public ScaleImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
}

public ScaleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
}

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if(ev.getPointerCount() == 1){
        switch(ev.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            tx = ev.getX();
            ty = ev.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if(!justScaled){
                dx = tx - ev.getX();
                dy = ty - ev.getY();
                tx -= dx;
                ty -= dy;
                int scrollX = (int)(this.getScrollX()/mScaleFactor);
                int scrollY = (int)(this.getScrollY()/mScaleFactor);
                if(Math.abs(scrollX+dx) > scrollLimitX) dx = 0;
                if(Math.abs(scrollY+dy) > scrollLimitY) dy = 0;
                this.scrollBy((int)(dx*mScaleFactor), (int)(dy*mScaleFactor));
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            justScaled = false;
            break;
        }
    }else if(ev.getPointerCount() == 2){
        justScaled = true;
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    x = this.getWidth()/2;
    y = this.getHeight()/2;
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, x ,y);
    int scrollX = (int)(this.getScrollX()/mScaleFactor);
    int scrollY = (int)(this.getScrollY()/mScaleFactor);
    if(Math.abs(scrollX) > scrollLimitX) dx = scrollLimitX - scrollX; else dx = 0;
    if(Math.abs(scrollY) > scrollLimitY) dy = scrollLimitY - scrollY; else dy = 0;
    this.scrollBy((int)(dx*mScaleFactor), (int)(dy*mScaleFactor));
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}

public void setScaleFactor(float mfactor){
    this.mScaleFactor = mfactor;
}

public float getScaleFactor(){
    return this.mScaleFactor;
}

public void setScrollLimit(int x, int y){
    this.scrollLimitX = x/2;
    this.scrollLimitY = y/2;
}

private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
        mScaleFactor = Math.max(1.0f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));
        ScaleImageView.this.invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}

}
```

To limit the image that at least one corner is inside the view:

```
// zoomImg is the Bitmap.
// mZoomImage is the ScaleImageView.
float scaleFactor = Math.min((float)(mZoomImage.getWidth())/zoomImg.getWidth(), (float)(mZoomImage.getHeight())/zoomImg.getHeight());
mZoomImage.setScrollLimit((int)(zoomImg.getWidth()*scaleFactor), (int)(zoomImg.getHeight()*scaleFactor));
```

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: I tried your solution, and images are getting scaled outside the view

Comment: To the above code, you need to find out the foucs (x,y) inside ScaleGestureDector and modified the (x,y) in onDraw(). May be you can search "zoom image" in Github.com which will gives you some other options.